# Is there any way I can fix or avoid errors when installing RTL8812AU driver?

Tags: linux, driver, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to install the Realtek-rtl8812au driver (Archer T4U V3) and I can't do anything because I get stuck at compile. It doesn't matter what package I clone from git or what driver package I am using, I can't compile properly. I tried different methods but the same result, compile error. I tried to compile without warnings treated as errors but it doesn't do anything.

Here is what says after I make the file:

```
> /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/osdep_service_linux.h:282:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  282 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
/home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/osdep_service_linux.h:283:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  283 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
In file included from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/drv_types.h:30,
                 from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/wifi.h: At top level:
/home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/wifi.h:1014: warning: "IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF" redefined
 1014 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF 0x40
      | 
In file included from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/osdep_service_linux.h:83,
                 from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/osdep_service.h:42,
                 from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
./include/linux/ieee80211.h:1657: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 1657 | #define IEEE80211_MAX_AMPDU_BUF  0x100
      | 
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1849: /home/ascii/Desktop/rtl88x2BU] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1794: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: did you try this one https://github.com/morrownr/8812au ? - It claims kernel compatibility : 5.9 - 5.14  ( while your is 5.11)

Comment: I didn't but I will try it, I'll be back.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny, sorry I'm late, I had some projects going on at Uni. I tried your package but I got other errors and I am sick of them, I will just downgrade my ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install the driver, I got a VM with Parrot Security (Debian 5 64bit) after many failures with Ubuntu. I found this site which helped me:
[Steps to install TP-Link Archer T4U Plus AC1300](https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/f723b966d5f42094619f9c1048c7838b)